# Illegal operation on empty result set. using LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the last created id in my table with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function, in a java code, but it does not work.

Here is my sql code :

```
    public static int lastInsertID() {
    int lastBillId = 0;
    try {
        Connexion conn = new Connexion();
         Statement stm = (Statement) conn.obtenirConnexion().createStatement();
         ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery("SELECT bill_id FROM bill WHERE bill_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
         res.next();
         lastbillId= res.getInt("bill_id");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }   
    return lastBillId;
}
```

[Here is my database bill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnUgF.png)

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pw3T.png)

And it sends me 0 as result.

Comment: You are not using PHPMyAdmin, but MySQL. PHPMyAdmin is just a web application to query a MySQL database.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the full exception stacktrace. The code shown by itself can't produce this error.

Comment: Does the table has any rows?

Comment: I edited my post with the added information. Yes the table as rows

Comment: I have solved the problem, I needed to do this sql code into the INSERT INTO part..

Comment: `lastbillId` is 0 because there's an exception thrown in `res.next();` line as the `ResultSet` is empty and never get assigned.

Comment: To make it clear [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) requires a `INSERT INTO` statement to happen first before it can be used on your MySQL session/connection, assuming the table has a `AUTO_INCREMENT` column

Comment: It looks like you are just wanting the last ID that was inserted? Take a look at the [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function and get the ID that way.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace as code-formatted text, not as a screenshot.